# ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'up' [-Wvla] in My code

Tags: c++, arrays

**ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'up' [-Wvla]|**

This error happened for this code.this code about a bill generator for an store.it takes unit prices and quantities for 100 items and returns sub total and have to enter discount manually.I used array in functions to code this program.but in the end this error happened.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int myVar=100;



void myinput (int up[],int qty[], int dr[]){
    cout<<"******************The Bill******************"<<endl;

   for (int i=0;i<myVar;i++)
    {
        cout<<"____________________________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nInput UNIT PRICE  of the      *"<<(i+1)<<"*  item  :";
        cin>>up[i];
        cout<<"Input QUANTITY of the         *"<<(i+1)<<"*  item :";
        cin>>qty[i];
        cout<<"Input DISCOUNT RATE of the    *"<<(i+1)<<"*  item :";
        cin>>dr[i];
        cout<<"____________________________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<""<<endl;
    }
}

void mytot(int up[],int qty[], int tot[]){
    for (int t=0;t<myVar;t++)
    {
        tot[t]=up[t]*qty[t];
    }
}


void mydis(int tot[],int dr[], int dis[]){
for (int a=0;a<myVar;a++)
   {
    dis[a]=tot[a]*dr[a]/100.0;
   }
}


void myst(int subtot[],int tot[],int dis[]){
    for(int g=0;g<myVar;g++)
    {
subtot[g]=tot[g]-dis[g];
    }
}

int mygt(int subtot[]){
    int gtot=0;
    for(int g=0;g<myVar;g++)
    {
        gtot=gtot+subtot[g];
    }
    return gtot;
}


void myout(int subtot[],int gtot){
    for(int o=0;o<myVar;o++)
    {   cout<<"____________________________________________"<<endl;
        cout<<"ITEM "<<o+1<<" SUB TOTAL IS  -    "<<subtot[o]<<" "<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"____________________________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"GRAND TOTAL IS             * "<<gtot<<"*";
    cout<<"\n============================================"<<endl;
}


int main(){

int up[myVar];
int qty[myVar];
int dr[myVar];
int dis[myVar];
int tot[myVar];
int subtot[myVar];
int gtot=0;

myinput(up,qty,dr);
mytot(up,qty,tot);
mydis(tot,dr,dis);
myst(subtot,tot,dis);
gtot= mygt(subtot);
myout(subtot,gtot);


cout<<"\n\n******************Thank You,Come Again******************"<<endl;
}
```

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Just use `std::vector` and stop using C arrays.

Comment: Just make `myVar` `const int`, this way array size will a compile-time constant, just initializing it with some value is not sufficient to make it usable as array size.

Comment: `myVar` is a variable, not a compile-time constant. And [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) does not exist in C++.

Comment: The error error pretty much explains it. in your `main()` function you have static arrays whose size cannot be determined during compile time. one way to fix it would be the use of `std::vector`, which will probably save you from some other headaches too, or you can make `myVar` a `const int`

Comment: strictly speaking there is nothing to solve, you simply cannot have static arrays with a dynamic size. Use `std::vector` instead

Comment: You could have removed 99% of this code and still shown the problem. And if you did that you might even have figured out the answer on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `myVar` is a non-constant variable, and you can't define arrays on the stack with a non-constant length. A few solutions for this are:

- Declare `myVar` as`const int myVar = 100;` to make it a constant, which is fitting for your code sample.
- Allocate your arrays on the heap with, for example, `int *up = new int[myVar];`.
- Use `std::vector` instead of arrays. `vector<int> up = new vector<int>(myVar)`.